# Increment values of an array using a for loop and a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have done a lot of research on google about it but I don't know how to achieve that in PHP. Actually I have an array with values and for each values I would like to get 5 new values incremented of 1.

Exemple :

```
$valueseg = array( 0 => 2510 , 1 => 1700);
```

I would like to get this result :

```
$valueseg = array( 0 => 2510, 1 => 2511, 2 => 2512, 3 => 2513, 4 => 2514 , 5 => 2515, 6 => 1700, , 7 => 1701, , 8 => 1702, , 9 => 1703, 10 => 1704 , 11 => 1705);
```

I tried to do that with a foreach and a for loop but I can't retrieve an array.

```
$tabasc = array();

foreach($valueseg as $key => $value){

    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $tabasc[$i] = $value + $i ;
    }
}
```

With an echo inside the for loop I have a result inline like this : 2478247924802481248225102511251225132514

And if I try to do a var_dump of $tabasc it shows me values incremented of 1 only for the first value of $valueseg.

Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Do `$tabasc[] = $value + $i ;` Then you won't overwrite the previous values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```
<?php

$valueseg = array( 0 => 2510 , 1=> 1700); 

$final_array = array(); //create a new array

foreach($valueseg as $values){ // iterate over your original array
  for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ // loop 5 times
    $final_array[] = $values+$i; //add incremented $i value to original value and assign to new array
  }

}

print_r($final_array); // print new array
```

Output:- https://eval.in/829546